# Is Binary Formatter good for MSMQ?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, message-queue

I'm using MSMQ to pass around XML.  However, I'd like to make the queue more generic, letting it accept class instances as messages.  That brings to mind the need for a binary formatter.

I've been reading about binary formatter and MSMQ.  It seems that by using binary formatter, I'm making MSMQ do something it really isn't meant to do.  In other words, I'm now passing binary based data on MSMQ when it wants to instead be very light and string based.  Or do I have that wrong?

What I've read is that more complex types of data (i.e., binary), should be stored in the database.  However, that probably presents its own issues since this data is serializable.

The data I'm passing isn't stream based.

If I'm going to leverage MSMQ, should it be used strictly for string based messages and not binary?

Comment: Light weight and string based are orthogonal - in fact, most binary serializers will require less bandwidth than the same data as string data (such as XML).

Answer (score 0):

> *It seems that by using binary formatter, I'm making MSMQ do something it really isn't meant to do.*

You are misinformed.  In fact, MSMQ ships with its own [BinaryMessageFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.binarymessageformatter.aspx) class, which is clearly intended to be used when you want to increase speed at the cost of some flexibility.

The documentation has this to say:

> The BinaryMessageFormatter is very efficient and can be used to
>   serialize most objects. The result is very compact and fast to parse,
>   but does not allow for loosely coupled messaging as the
>   [XmlMessageFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.xmlmessageformatter.aspx) does. Loosely coupled means that the client and
>   the server can independently version the type that is sent and
>   received.
>
> When the application sends a message to the queue using an instance of
>   the MessageQueue class, the formatter serializes the object into a
>   stream and inserts it into the message body. When reading from a queue
>   using a MessageQueue, the formatter deserializes the message data into
>   the Body property of a Message.
>
> BinaryMessageFormatter provides faster throughput than the
>   XmlMessageFormatter. Use the BinaryMessageFormatter when pure speed
>   rather than loosely coupled messaging is desired.